Pdfium print actual size instead of resizing to page
I do receive shipping labels from a third party. They labels are actually A6 size, but printed on A4 pdf page. I created a vb.net script to execute a API call to receive the files and want to print them afterwards using Pdfium with no user input or any preview.
I am trying to print actual size of the document and print the A6 part in the upper left corner of the A4 page on a A6 label printer.
Unfortunately I am not able to scale the document to actual size using Pdfium. I tried CutMargin already but squeezes the complete A4 page on the A6 label when printing.
Any suggestions to either remove the white space, or to print actual size?
Dim document As PdfDocument = PdfDocument.Load(pdfPath)
        'Using document As PdfDocument = PdfDocument.Load(pdfPath)
        ' Erstelle einen neuen PrintDocument
        Using printDoc = document.CreatePrintDocument(PdfiumViewer.PdfPrintMode.CutMargin)
            ' Setze den Drucker
            printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName
            printDoc.Print()

        End Using

Thanks
Andreas

The source file I get is a A6 print, but placed on a A4 pdf document. This is what I get from third party. So now I am trying to print the A4 pdf file on a A6 printer and get rid of the white blanks.
